# is a read or write operation on a pointer value atomic in golang?

Tags: multithreading, go, atomic

Is the size of a pointer value 32 bits or 64 bits in golang when building with `GOARCH=amd64` option specified and running on 64-bit OS?

If it's 64-bit size, is a global pointer value 8-byte aligned in memory so that a read or write operation of that pointer value is carried out atomically?

For example, in the following code, is it possible that the global pointer p is only partially updated when the read goroutine read the pointer?

```
var p *int

void main() {
    i := 1
    p = &i
    go func() {
        fmt.Println(*p)
    }()
}
```

The scenario I'm concerning is that there is only one write but multiple reads on a global pointer value, and reading of an old value of the pointer is not important. Thanks in advance!

Comment: No. The only atomic operations are through `sync/atomic`. You always need to synchronize reads and writes.

Comment: [See also](http://stackoverflow.com/q/41406501/720999).