# Golang's bytes.Buffer thread safety for one writer/one reader

Tags: go, io, buffer, slice

I know that golang's `bytes.Buffer` is not thread-safe but if I have one writer (in a goroutine) and one reader (in another goroutine). Is it safe?

If not, then why is it not? Write appends to the buffer while reads read from the start so I don't see a scenario where they will be accessing the same memory location.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

No, it's not safe.

[`bytes.Buffer`](https://golang.org/pkg/bytes/#Buffer) is a struct, and both the [`Buffer.Read()`](https://golang.org/pkg/bytes/#Buffer.Read) and [`Buffer.Write()`](https://golang.org/pkg/bytes/#Buffer.Write) methods read / modify the same fields of the same struct value (they have pointer receivers). This alone is enough to be unsafe for concurrent use. For more details, see [Is it safe to read a function pointer concurrently without a lock?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41406501/is-it-safe-to-read-a-function-pointer-concurrently-without-a-lock/41407827#41407827)

Also think about that a `bytes.Buffer` stores bytes in a byte slice, which is a field of the struct. When writing, it might be necessary to sometimes allocate a bigger buffer (if slice capacity is not enough), and so the slice header (the slice struct field) must be changed (in `Write()`). Without synchronization there's no guarantee that a concurrent `Read()` will see this.

And... even if no reallocation is needed (because the underlying byte slice has enough capacity to accommodate the data passed to `Write()`), storing the data in the byte slice requires to reslice it, so the slice header changes even if no reallocation is needed (the length of the slice is also part of the slice header).  To see what's in the slice header, check out the [`reflect.SliceHeader`](https://golang.org/pkg/reflect/#StringHeader) type.