# Golang concurrency write to variable - why this code works?

Tags: go, concurrency, locking, mutex, shared-memory

I'm learning concurrency-related issues in Golang. I wrote some code:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "time"
)

func incr(num *int) {
    *num = *num + 1

}

func main() {
    var a = 0

    for i := 0; i < 50; i++ {
        go incr(&a)
    }

    incr(&a)

    time.Sleep(1 * time.Second)
    fmt.Println(a)
}
```

The result of this code is: 51

In this code I've declared `a` variable which I'm increasing in 50 running goroutines. What I've read and unsterstood this code should fail because multiple goroutines are writing to same memory address. In this case I should add `sync.Mutex` lock in order to fix that.

Code is available in the playground: https://play.golang.org/p/Tba9pfpxaHY

Could You explain what is really happening in this program?

Comment: It doesn't work. You just got "lucky". Perhaps you're running on a single-CPU machine (such as the Go playground)? Run it with the race detector (`go run -race`).

Comment: IMO, This is why concurrent programming is next level difficult :) No explicit errors or panics, may work under observation.  While it's *extremely* likely that the race detector detects this specific race condition there are conditions/situations where the race detector will NOT detect anything.  This is where IMO we need to still fall back on first principles and learn to recognize all concurrent accesses (https://medium.com/dm03514-tech-blog/golang-candidates-and-contexts-a-heuristic-approach-to-race-condition-detection-e2b230e70d08) and guard by default

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Guess what? I ran your app and I get varying outputs: sometimes `49,` sometimes `48`, sometimes `50` (and sometimes `51`).

If you run your app with the race detector enabled (`go run -race play.go`), it tells you have data races:

```
==================
WARNING: DATA RACE
Read at 0x00c00009a010 by goroutine 7:
  main.incr()
      /home/icza/gows/src/play/play.go:9 +0x3a

Previous write at 0x00c00009a010 by goroutine 6:
  main.incr()
      /home/icza/gows/src/play/play.go:9 +0x50

Goroutine 7 (running) created at:
  main.main()
      /home/icza/gows/src/play/play.go:17 +0x83

Goroutine 6 (finished) created at:
  main.main()
      /home/icza/gows/src/play/play.go:17 +0x83
==================
```

When you have data races, the behavior of your app is **undefined**. "Seemingly working sometimes" also fits into the "undefined" behavior, but undefined also means it can do anything else too.

See related questions:

[Assign a map to another map is safety in golang?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56001748/assign-a-map-to-another-map-is-safety-in-golang/56001821#56001821)

[Is it safe to read a function pointer concurrently without a lock?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41406501/is-it-safe-to-read-a-function-pointer-concurrently-without-a-lock/41407827#41407827)

[golang struct concurrent read and write without Lock is also running ok?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51301328/golang-struct-concurrent-read-and-write-without-lock-is-also-running-ok/51301572#51301572)

Comment: I'd also point at [this classic piece](https://software.intel.com/en-us/blogs/2013/01/06/benign-data-races-what-could-possibly-go-wrong) by one of the folks behind that race detector ;-)

Comment: @kostix Yes, that link is also included in one of my linked answers, but it can't hurt to advertise it more.