# how to create a real race condition in golang

Tags: pointers, go, concurrency, race-condition, goroutine

### problem description

Recently I learned the option `-race` to check the exist of race condition in go. The full command is `go run -race xxx.go` It really helped me a lot. But as with the code below, I think the check result is wrong, and tried a lot of method (**My try to get a panic** below) to get a **REAL** panic but failed. So I want to know whether the code is correct and the race check is wrong，or can you revise my code so that I can **SEE** a real panic. Thanks a lot.

#### The code

```
package main
import "fmt"

type myType struct {
    A int
}

func main(){
    c:=make(chan bool)
    x := new(myType)
    go func(){
        x = new(myType) // write to x
        c <- true
    }()
    _ = *x // read from x
    <-c
    fmt.Println("end")
}
```

#### The race check result

`go run -race test.go`

```
==================
WARNING: DATA RACE
Write at 0x00c00009c010 by goroutine 6:
  main.main.func1()
      /Users/yaodongen/test.go:12 +0x56

Previous read at 0x00c00009c010 by main goroutine:
  main.main()
      /Users/yaodongen/test.go:15 +0xe2

Goroutine 6 (running) created at:
  main.main()
      /Users/yaodongen/test.go:11 +0xd4
==================
end
Found 1 data race(s)
exit status 66
```

#### My point

I tried to find the reason for the race condition report.In a [post](https://blog.betacat.io/post/golang-atomic-value-exploration/)(Chinese), it mentions that the operation `a = in64(0)` is not atomic. For example in one 32 bit Machine and the data like int64 may be 64 bit length, CPU could copy half of the data and be interruptted by others. In the following code (**Prove the golang copy is not atomic**), I write a code to prove its true. But in my case, the code `x = new(myType)` is to copy a pointer value, and I think it can be done in one CPU copy. In other word, the operation is atomic and will never reach race condition.

#### Prove the golang copy is not atomic

```
package main
import "fmt"
import "time"

func main(){
    var x = [...]int{1,1,1,1,1,1}
    c := make(chan int, 100)
    go func(){
        for i:=0;;i++{
            if i&1 == 0 {
                x = [...]int{2,2,2,2,2,2} // write to x
            }else{
                x = [...]int{1,1,1,1,1,1} // write to x
            }
            c<-0 // let other goroutine see the change of x
            <-c
        }
    }()
    go func(){
        for {
            d := x                    // read from x
            if d[0] != d[5] {
                fmt.Println(d)
                panic("error")        // proved the copy operation is not atomic
            }
            c<-0
            <-c
        }
    }()
    time.Sleep(time.Millisecond * 10000)
    fmt.Println("end")
}
```

#### My try to get a panic

But it failed, the code will panic if there exists a race condition (wrong memory address).

```
package main
import "fmt"
import "time"

type myType struct {
    A int
}

func main(){
    x := new(myType)
    c := make(chan int, 100)
    go func(){
        for {
            x = new(myType) // write to x
            c<-0
            <-c
        }
    }()
    for i:=0; i<4; i++{
        go func(){
            for {
                _ = *x // if exists a race condition, `*x` will visit a wrong memory address, and will panic
                c<-0
                <-c
            }
        }()
    }
    time.Sleep(time.Second * 10)
    fmt.Println("end")
}
```

Comment: you probably dont know all implementation details of all architectures, stay safe, dont try to be smart.

Comment: Being atomic or not does not matter for being a race or not. Writing to to addresses concurrently is racy, **no** **matter** whether the underlying architecture may or may not do atomic writes or not. Go abstracts over these details and if the race detector says your code is racy, then your code is racy and thus buggy.

Comment: Thanks for your advice. I should never do that in my project.

Answer (score 4):

Go's race detection never gives false positives. If it tells you there's a race, then there *is* a race. It might not recognize all races (they have to happen to be detectable), but what it finds is always positive (bugs in the race detector not counting).

The race condition in your example is clear and simple. You have 2 goroutines, one reads a variable and the other one writes it without synchronization. This is the recipe for a race condition.

Race conditions make your app unpredictable. A race condition's behavior is undefined. Any experienced behavior falls under undefined, including the lack of panic. Don't tempt the devil, if there's a race condition, use proper synchronization. End of story.

See [Is it safe to read a function pointer concurrently without a lock?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41406501/is-it-safe-to-read-a-function-pointer-concurrently-without-a-lock/41407827#41407827)

Comment: Thanks, I agree with your point in the other question. `One could take your code as a starting point, extend / build on it and result in a catastrophe due to your initially "unharmful" data race.`

Comment: [An obligatory essay on "benign" data races from one of the Go core devs](https://software.intel.com/en-us/blogs/2013/01/06/benign-data-races-what-could-possibly-go-wrong).